# Uncaught SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode in chrome 40

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app, google-crawlers

Our `ReactJS` application created using `create-react-app` is not getting indexed in google. Upon investigation, found out that google crawler is using `Chrome v40` engine to parse client side apps. So I got hold of `Chrome 40` and tried to load the page. I got an error in console saying

> Loading chunk 13 failed. Uncaught SyntaxError: Use of const in strict
>   mode.

I tried to apply polyfill (`babel` polyfill as well as some others) but this error is not going away.

Any advise? Is there anything I can do to make `create-react-app` to correctly transpile the code to `Chrome 40` compatible ?

Comment: had you ejected your app? do you have any custom configs? please provide your **package.json** file as well as any external configs for babel if any

Comment: No, I haven't ejected the app. added package.js to ttps://jsfiddle.net/gmzen3yw/ please check. I tried to add a browser list to the package.js to control babel transpiling. but no success

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gmzen3yw/

Comment: It seems that at least for now asset https://b2cbeta.akbartravels.com/visa/static/js/main.3267b2fd.js is OK and doesn't contain any `const` keyword. May be is it cache? Also what is the console which has this error?

Answer (score 0):

The issue happened because i was using a component which was not compatible. https://github.com/yahoo/react-stickynode. It worked perfectly after i removed this.